# bash (potentiallly can use perl/python): filter space delimited arg list through regexes

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a set of regexes which should be tested against each item in a space delimited list.

I want these items to be able to have spaces in them which will be escaped. So:

```
abc def\ ghi jkl abc
```

consists of 4 items, `abc`, `def ghi`, `jkl`, and `abc`.

If my set of regexes is

```
b
k$
^g
```

the output should be

```
abc abc
```

It seems like `grep -f` can get me most of the way there but I have to deal with a way to handle the escaped spaces so I can't just do a `tr` from space to newline.

Edit: I think I could just use `sed` to do an escaped-space aware replacement of regular spaces to newlines. And `tr` is sufficient on the way back from newlines. Wondering if anyone has any better ideas.

Comment: How are your items given? are they in a string, in an array, user given, taken from a file...?

Comment: one way you could do it would be to replace all escaped spaces with non-secable spaces (a utf-8 character), so then they won't match space regexps. And once you're over, replace the non-secable space with a regular space. A bit hackish, but could be an easy way to get around.

Comment: It comes over STDIN. Out of a program (from a pipe)

Comment: @zmo, hmm, using the `tr` twice (space to \n, then \n back to space) already seems too hackish.

Comment: Can you make this program output each item separately, one line each?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I guess.. but I'd still need to get them back into that format so I'd have to `tr` the `\n`s to spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand how your items are given.

Pretending that they come from the output of a program *mystery*, in one line, e.g.,

```
gniourf@somewhere$ mystery
abc def\ ghi jkl abc
```

you could (file *myscript*):

```
#!/bin/bash

output=()

re=( 'b' 'k$' '^g' ) # array of your regexes

read -a a
for w in "${a[@]}"; do
    for r in "${re[@]}"; do
        if [[ $w =~ $r ]]; then
            output+=( "${w// /\\ }" ) # replace space with backslash-space
            break
        fi
    done
done
echo "${output[@]}"
```

For testing purpose, I made this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file mystery
echo 'abc def\ ghi jkl abc'
```

Then (after `chmod +x mystery myscript`):

```
gniourf@somewhere$ ./mystery
abc def\ ghi jkl abc
gniourf@somewhere$ ./mystery | ./myscript
abc abc
```

*Caveat*. This will break sooner or later, unless *mystery* always outputs decent stuff!

Comment: Oh nice. a native bash loop doing bash regexes. That's legit!

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be handled in bash itself without any external utility.

First put your strings in an array:

```
input=(abc 'def ghi' jkl abc)
```

Then run this for loop to validate your input against provided regex:

```
for i in "${input[@]}"; do
    for r in 'b' 'k$' '^g'; do
       [[ "$i" =~ $r ]] && echo $i && break
    done
done
```

**OUTOUT:**

```
abc
abc
```

Comment: Should probably have a `break` in the inner loop, so you don't echo the same input twice if it matches multiple regexps.

Comment: @Barmar: Good point, thanks so much. I added break in inner for loop.

Comment: @StevenLu: I would like to add 1 more point. If for some reason you're getting `escaped space` strings like `'abc\ def\ xyz'` some somewhere then you can use: `"${str//\\/}"` to strip all backward slashes while populating input array.